# VLQ Review queue Recommend Deletion description

Tags: feature-request, review-queues, low-quality-posts

The description for Recommend Deletion action in the VLQ review queue is pretty silly:

> **Recommend Deletion** to recommend that this answer be deleted

A new user can figure that out on their own. Can we change this to some more descriptive like the other actions have? For example:

> **Recommend Deletion** if this post cannot reasonably be improved to our quality standard.

Comment: Wow, I hadn't realized the description for that is so bad. "Recommend Deletion to Recommend Deletion" - Tautology anyone?

Comment: @animuson Any idea if this is prevalent on other Stack Exchange sites?

Comment: @animuson "Improve Edit the edit by making additional corrections"

Comment: Sounds like Doxygen documentation..